# Can I install a theme via usb?

Tags: pi-zero, retropie

I have a Raspberry PI Zero and have installed Retropie onto the SD card. This works great and is running games that I have on the SD card.

It is using Emulation Station to play the games.

However, I want to install a new theme as the default doesn't work well with my screen (text too small).

The main issue is, I can only update the SD card by connecting a USB stick and letting it auto-copy files.

So for example, when I copy ROM files, I create a blank USB with a folder called "retropie". I connect it to the Zero and it creates a set of subfolders: BIOS, Configs, roms. I can then plug it back in my Windows machine and copy the rom files to the correct sub-folders.

Is there something I can do like this to install themes? If so, what should the folder structure be for themes?

If it matters, [this is the specific theme](https://github.com/rxbrad/es-theme-gbz35) I want to install at the moment.